# Are there any good tools with GUI for pdf/djvu tagging and searching by tags?

Tags: pdf, metadata, tags, djvu

I've been long using FastPhotoTagger for jpg/png/mp4 tagging and searching. While the tool suffices for my personal needs, someone asked me if I could recommend an equally good tool for pdf/djvu tagging, which made me stumble. Because I am accustomed to using a simple folder structure to group and keep the only pdf files that I have. While the person who asks is seemingly an owner of a larger collection.

The only contribution to the question from my side would be if there is any way to assign tags to separate pages of pdf files rather than the whole file? Surely, I'd expect such tags for such pages to be quickly searchable too with or without the use of the same tool.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few years ago with https://openpaper.work/en/, it didn't work for me because I have the collection well organized, but if you have your pdf's disorganized it might work.
Peter